# Initializing a MultipleChoiceField in Django CMS

Tags: python, django, forms, django-cms

I have a `CharField` (`displayed_fields`) in my model that I display in my form as a `MultipleChoiceField`. Currently, the form loads with nothing selected, even if the model's `displayed_fields` is non-empty.

I'd like the form to initialize to the previously selected items being selected. So far, I've tried addint different values of `intial`, including `initial=ExamplePlugin.EMAIL_COLUMN` and `initial={'displayed_fields': ['name', 'office', 'phone']}`, to `forms.py`'s field declaration, which doesn't seem to change anything. Is it possible to initialize it like this, and if not, is there a better model to be using than `CharField`?

`models.py`:

```
class ExamplePlugin(CMSPlugin):
    NAME_COLUMN = 'name'
    OFFICE_COLUMN = 'office'
    PHONE_COLUMN = 'phone'
    EMAIL_COLUMN = 'email'
    TITLE_COLUMN = 'title'

    COLUMN_CHOICES = (
        (NAME_COLUMN, 'First and Last Name'),
        (OFFICE_COLUMN, 'Office Location'),
        (PHONE_COLUMN, 'Phone Number'),
        (EMAIL_COLUMN, 'Email Address'),
        (TITLE_COLUMN, 'Title'),
    )

    displayed_fields = models.CharField(blank=False, verbose_name='Fields to show', max_length=255)
```

`forms.py`:

```
class ExampleForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    displayed_fields = MultipleChoiceField(choices=ExamplePlugin.COLUMN_CHOICES, help_text="Select columns that you would like to appear.")

    class Meta:
        model = ExamplePlugin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should do:

```
class ExampleForm(ModelForm):
    displayed_fields = MultipleChoiceField(choices=ExamplePlugin.COLUMN_CHOICES, help_text="Select columns that you would like to appear.", initial=['name', 'office', 'phone'])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = ExamplePlugin
```

MultipleChoiceField accepts a list as its default, I guess.

Comment: Hmm, still no selected fields on initialization. Did you mean to put `displayed_fields`'s declaration under `__init__` though, or is it just like that because I accidentally had it like that in the question at first?

Comment: @MiloPrice Sorry. It should not go inside \_\_init__. fixed it